# Android Studio : Error : unable to start daemon process

Tags: android-studio

I am using windows 10 and when I create a new project in android studio it gives the error.

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.  
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.  
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM

Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

close the android studio and and restart by run as administrator.